# query for rest of the items in the table.some are already existing in another

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

i am using sql server mambership in asp.net for website creation.i have a table with all products.here i have user with some products which are existing in the all products.Now i want to show rest of the products which are not existing with the user from all products.plz help me. iam using grid to represent the product.
i need a query whch satisfies my condition thank you

Comment: really, really short of detailed information....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `left outer join` against your `UserProducts` table and check for `ProductID is null`.

Example with some dummy data in table variables instead of real tables.

```
-- Products table with all products
declare @Products table (ProductID int, ProductName varchar(10))

-- Products connected to a user
declare @UserProducts table (UserID int, ProductID int)

-- Add all products to products table
insert into @Products(ProductID, ProductName) values
(1, 'Prod 1'),
(2, 'Prod 2'),
(3, 'Prod 3'),
(4, 'Prod 4'),
(5, 'Prod 5')

-- Add products already connected to user
insert into @UserProducts(UserID, ProductID) values
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(2, 3)

-- Fetch all products for UserID = 1
declare @UserID int = 1

select A.ProductID,
       A.ProductName
from @Products as A
  left outer join @UserProducts U
    on A.ProductID = U.ProductID and
       U.UserID = @UserID
where U.ProductID is null
```

Result:

```
ProductID   ProductName
----------- -----------
3           Prod 3
4           Prod 4
5           Prod 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You're question isn't very clear, do you have a list of product ids perhaps? How are the tables formatted?

You probably want something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM products_all
WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

In that scenario, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are the ids that your user has.